# Chrome crashes when opened multiple windows(Say 80) via selenium webdriver in linux server

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to check on what criteria the chrome crashes if we open multiple chrome windows via python selenium webdriver code. So I am running a iteration until it crashes. Note: It's not one chrome window with multiple tabs. Its actually multiple windows itself with 1 empty tab each.
I am getting below 3 errors once its unable to spawn new window. But on what backend restriction the chrome is getting crashed. Is there any memory limit for chrome or thread limit or processes limit that triggers crash.?

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

flag = 1
while flag:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    except:
        flag = 0
```

**Error-1:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

**Error-2:**

```
File "/../../python/current/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1231, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**Error-3:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```